# Мини корзина на Joomla! 2.5+VM 3

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

День!
Подскажите код вызова стандартного компонента мини корзины Joomla2.5+VM3. Мне нужно разместить её в шапке шаблона, но я не понимаю как к ней обратится

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашёл такое - в нужном месте шаблона вставил код:

```
<?
$cart_empty = 1;
if(!class_exists('VmConfig')){
    require_once(JPATH_SITE.'/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/config.php');
    VmConfig::loadConfig();
}
if(!class_exists('VirtueMartCart')){
    require_once(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/cart.php');
}
$cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart(false);
$data = $cart->prepareAjaxData();
foreach ($data->products as $product){
    $p_sum[] = $product['prices'];
}
echo array_sum($p_sum); 
?>
```

Таким образом я получил сумму товаров корзине, что для мини корзины уже не плохо.